# substitute to stderr in gdb for lldb

Tags: gdb, lldb, cpython

in `gdb`, when one wants to print an object, then one could use,

```
call PyObject_Print($0, stderr, 1)
```

but this gives an error in `lldb`, what is the substitute to using `stderr`?

context -
I built python from source and then was printing an object in `lldb`
I cloned git repository of cpython, then ran,

```
./configure
make
```

then ran,

```
lldb
(lldb) target create python.exe
(lldb) b main
(lldb) call PyLong_FromLong(11111)
(lldb) call PyObject_Print($0, stderr, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`stderr` is required by POSIX to be a macro, so it doesn't generally exist in debug information.  gdb's expression parser probably has special handling for this token, which is why it's working there..

lldb's expression parser tries to stick as close to the source language as we can manage, so we don't inject this sort of assist.  You will have to provide `stderr` to the expression parser somehow just as a normal compile would.

One fairly easy way to get your hands on what stderr really is for use in expressions is to find out what the define resolves to on your system, and use that manually.  So for instance, on macOS, stdio.h has:

```
extern FILE *__stderrp;
#define stderr  __stderrp
```

So you can do:

```
(lldb) expr fprintf(__stderrp, "Some error text.\n")
Some error text.
(int) $1 = 17
```

If you are building with clang, and your system headers have clang module maps (as described here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html), you can tell clang to use that module for the libraries it imports with the `-fmodules` flag.   That module import gets recorded in the debug information and lldb will use that record to find the clang module and merge it with the rest of the debug info.  That's a fairly straightforward way to recover macros in a debug session.

So if your system headers are modular you can do:

```
$ clang -fmodules -g -O0 example.c -o example
```

to build your binary with modules enabled, and then accessing the macro in the expression parser will "just work":

```
(lldb) expr fprintf(stderr, "Some error text.\n")
Some error text.
(int) $0 = 17
```

Comment: I think so configuration uses gcc, instead of clang, I specified EXTRA_CFLAGS="-fmodules" during configuration, but I still get error while using lldb.

Comment: I don't think gdb has special handling for `stderr`, but instead in [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdio.h;h=e6425341cec4eeaf8756c1cd46549ff61d1e15e7;hb=HEAD#l149) it's defined as `#define stderr stderr`, and that's why it works.

Comment: clang writes a record of the imported module in the DWARF, which is what lldb picks up on to auto-import the module for you.  Maybe there's some difference in the DWARF emitted that's causing this not to work.  If you are so motivated, you could file a bug with the llvm.org bug tracker which is now https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.

Comment: The original post didn't show the error, so I can't tell for sure.  If there's a real symbol called stderr - which there has to be for the define to work - lldb should have picked that up.  If the error was that we don't know the type of stderr, then you can work around that by casting it to a (FILE *).